# How to get the order attribute of a page

Tags: pages, page-attributes

As we know we can sort pages in a query by their page order attribute, I can't figure out how to get this number to use it for a conditional and the max number listed

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Try with `echo get_post_field('menu_order', $post->ID);`

(or `$post->menu_order`)